# Magento - downloadable product freezes browser

Tags: magento, download, magento-1.4

I am running a live Magento CE 1.4.0.1 site. It sells downloadable files (only).

At the moment it's not possible for a customer to download two purchased files simultaneously. By this I mean clicking the first product's link, and, while it is downloading, click the second, and have both downloading at the same time.

Instead, when a customer downloads the first file, it freezes the browser. No areas of the site will accept clicked input while the sound is downloading. After the download completes, browser activity returns to normal.

This problem also occurs on CE 1.7.  There's a report on the forums, but no solution yet:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/69428/

Customers would like to download all their purchases simultaneously. They also get confused when additional clicking on the website is not possible, and believe their browser has crashed.

Any suggestions to allow simultaneous downloads?

Many thanks in advance for your thoughts.